# matriz inverter position C

Tags: c

I tried to invert using the loop but on the second iteration the result was not expected,

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
 setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
 printf("Exercício de Fixação - Inverter as Linhas da Matriz\n");
 int matriz[2][2];
 matriz[0][1]= 50;
 matriz[0][0]= 52;
 matriz[1][1]= 31;
 matriz[1][0]= 13;

 //matriz  in descending positionte
 for(int linha=0 ; 2 > linha; linha++){
     for(int coluna=0 ; 2 > coluna; coluna++){
       printf("%d ", matriz[linha][coluna]);
         }
        printf("\n");
     }

  //inverted matrix
 for(int  linha=2; linha > 0 ; linha--){
    for(int  coluna=2; coluna > 0 ; coluna--){
      printf("%d \n", matriz[linha][coluna]);
   }
printf("\n");
  }



}
```

The way I did it is not working, :/

why is that even reversing the position in the loop the result not following the loop instruction

Comment: Why was it not expected? What did you get? What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

When counting in reverse, you're starting the index at 2 and ending at 1.  You need to adjust these to start at 1 and end at 0.

```
 for(int  linha=1; linha >= 0 ; linha--){
    for(int  coluna=1; coluna >= 0 ; coluna--){
      printf("%d \n", matriz[linha][coluna]);
   }
   printf("\n");
  }
```